# NestJS throw http exepction from guard (export as library module)

Tags: typescript, exception, nestjs

I'm making a nestjs library where I include a guard as part of the module,

I try to throw http error from guard, but the context was lost in controller it will just throw 500 instead.

It works fine if I import the library as source code instead of dist build.

```js
@Injectable()
export class SignedUrlGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private readonly signedUrlService: SignedUrlService,
    ) { }

    canActivate(
        context: ExecutionContext,
    ): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
        const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        return this.validateRequest(request, request.query);
    }

    private validateRequest(request: Request, query: Record<string, string>): boolean {
        try {
            return this.signedUrlService.isSignatureValid(request, query)
        } catch (error) {
            throw new ForbiddenException('Invalid url ,with custom error message')
        }
    }
}
```

```js
"devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.4.4",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.8",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3",
    "prettier": "^2.1.2",
    "eslint": "^7.12.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.14.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.5.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.4.4",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.4.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13"
  }
```

tsconfig

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2019",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./lib",
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["lib/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "test", "**/*spec.ts"]
}
```

You can check full code here
https://github.com/vh13294/nestjs-signed-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

npm install via file based system won't work

to solve this problem try

npm pack

then install from the tgz file